# Qt program crashes after deleting last object from a vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, erase, qlistwidget

I have an application I'm making for my work. It basically takes in employees and their availability and makes a schedule. With that aside, I have a page called "edit employee" in which I can edit information from any employee. I have a "delete" button in which when you press it, you get the current row from the *qlistwidget* and it deletes that element. It all works, until I only have one element left in the vector.

I have tried the different forms of deleting from a vector. I tried *.clear()*, *.erase(vec.begin(), vec.end())*, *.erase(vec.begin() + position)*, etc.

I also had a *for* loop displaying the contents of the vector, it showed only 1 element in the vector, which was correct. The vector did not have empty spaces or anything that you could consider "corrupted".

```
void MainWindow::deleteEmployee(int position)
{
//    employeeList.erase(employeeList.begin() + position);

    if(employeeList.size() == 1)
    {
        // fails only when trying to delete from last index
        employeeList.clear();
    }
    else
    {
        employeeList.erase(employeeList.begin() + position);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_editEmployeeDelete_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply =
       QMessageBox::question(this, "Delete Employee",
           "Are you sure you want to delete " + 
           employeeList.at(ui->editEmployee_listWidget->currentRow()).getFirstName() +
           " " +
           employeeList.at(ui->editEmployee_listWidget->currentRow()).getLastName() +
           "?",
           QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);

    if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Success",
            employeeList.at(ui->editEmployee_listWidget->currentRow()).getFirstName() +
            " " +
            employeeList.at(ui->editEmployee_listWidget->currentRow()).getLastName() +
            " has been deleted successfully.");

        deleteEmployee(ui->editEmployee_listWidget->currentRow());

        // clears the qlistwidget once again to add all employees left in the vector
        ui->editEmployee_listWidget->blockSignals(true);
        ui->editEmployee_listWidget->clear();
        ui->editEmployee_listWidget->blockSignals(false);

        // adds all the employees names to the qlistwidget
        for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++)
        {
            ui->editEmployee_listWidget->addItem(employeeList.at(i).getLastName() +
                                                 ", " +
                                                 employeeList.at(i).getFirstName());
        }
    }
}
```

*employeeList* is a vector of type employee, which is a class I created. It holds their name, ranking, etc (all QStrings and ints).

When you click on the *qlistwidget*, the delete button becomes enabled. When you click on the delete button, the selected employee will be deleted. This works perfectly fine until you have 1 person left, in which it crashes, stating "Program has unexpectedly finished". I have tried many different forms of deleting. None worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What type is being stored in the vector?  Please specify this, as if it is an object (not a pointer), then the destructor of that object comes into play when you remove it from the vector.  Second, `employeeList.clear()` will never fail unless 1) `employeeList` is not a valid object or 2) the destructor of the item(s) being cleared are faulty or 3) a race condition is occurring and 2 or more threads are trying to clear the vector simultaneously.  It can't really be anything else.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie I added a small description of employeeList. would you like me to post the entire employee class? And also, would having a vector of objects be the case as to why it doesnt work?

Comment: Please show the `employeeList` class.  Also, when you debug, exactly where is the error occurring internally?  Just stating that "Program has unexpectedly finished" and nothing else is a sign that you need to do some more in-depth debugging.

Comment: employeeList is a private data member vector within MainWindow. its object type is employee which only hold the information of that specific employee. is the employee class what you are looking for? The vector is literally just vector<employee> employeeList    And also, I attempted to debug the program, and only crashes when hitting the clear line inside the if statement in which it checks if there is only one element. If I get rid of the line, the program obviously works, as it doesn’t delete anything, so it is definitely the clear line in which the problem occurs

Comment: I suppose your problem is that `currentRow` returns -1 when listwidget is empty. And this value is passed into delete function, then the code crashes. You should add some conditions to check whether item from vector can be deleted by `erase`.

Comment: @rafix07 I don’t delete the element until after I get the location. Currentrow isnt the problem, as when i cout it, it gives me 0. Also, when there are more elements in the vector, it allows me to delete the correct element using that index

Comment: @OscarLopez You really need to debug into what in `clear` is causing the issue.  I bet the issue is one of the 3 items I mentioned earlier.  Take your pick of the 3.  It also doesn't help when you don't have, in code, a check to ensure the position is valid.   Let's see a change in the code where you are actually checking the `position`, instead of assuming that it is good (doing a `cout` doesn't prove to us the position is not faulty, as we do not have access to your monitor).